# Why do I randomly lose Anarchy stacks?

Tags: borderlands-2

When trying out Gaige, the Mechromancer class, I was trying out the Anarchy skill, which adds an "Anarchy" stack every time you kill or reload after emptying your magazine. It's supposed to lose stacks when you reload a non-empty mag or while you're in Fight for your Life.

However, I found I constantly just *lost* stacks for no reason. Even after mapping my Reload key so I couldn't press it and not dying, I would randomly find myself with zero stacks. A friend playing in the same game with the skill noticed the same problem, but he was able to gather many many stacks, mine rarely went above 10 before being randomly lost.

Is there some unstated reason you can lose Anarchy stacks? Is this a bug or is there some logic to how I'm losing stacks?

Comment: I read a review that some skills consume Anarchy stacks to boost their functionality.  Perhaps that's part of it?

Comment: @fbueckert possible, but at level 10 I don't have many other skills. Maybe the Close Enough skill eats them? I'll try that out.

Comment: I noticed something that will really benefit you if you have high anarchy stacks and you are underleveled.  Apparently entering **Fight for your Life** when being knocked out from a barrel will not cause you to lose anarchy stacks.  If you have a buddy around our you think you can get a kill, this would be a great way to preserve your stacks when you are very close to dying.  I think indirect explosions cause this to happen too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue with the Anarchy skill that causes Mechromancers in multi-player games who are **not** the game host to randomly lose their stacks of Anarchy. Also note that you will rapidly lose stacks while in Fight For Your Life mode, and may lose stacks when fueling skills such as Death From Above, Discord, or With Claws.

Comment: Yeah, we were both not the host...that sounds like it's probably it.

Comment: @BenBrocka I wish I had a more conclusive source for you, but there are **oodles** of reports of it all over Gearbox's forums. Apparently it's worse with fully-auto guns, as well.

Comment: I've been using a 10.3 fire rate Anarchist...so yeah pretty full auto.

Comment: Ah well I think I found out why. As a guest player, some automatic reloads are being registered as early reloads due to synchronization issues and thus you get penalized for it.  You can see it clearly if you have the **Discord** skill.

Comment: Best I can tell this seems to be fixed now, probably a recent patch

Answer (score 0):

As fbueckert said, it is entirely possible that you're consuming Anarchy to fuel your other skills. If you're shooting while in mid-air, that will consume Anarchy stacks to fuel your Death From Above skill. And melee-ing while you have at least one stack of Anarchy will consume one stack for your With Claws skills (which I'm thinking is a typo of "Witch Claws").

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this happens when you switch weapons from your backpack to your equipped weapon or it may happen when you switch weapons before you use up an entire clip of ammo. Only when you're not the host.